# GIFs will not animate when sent via Facebook Messenger API

Tags: facebook, animation, gif, facebook-messenger

I can send text messages and regular images via Facebook Messenger's API. However, when I send GIFs, only a single frame is shown on the receiving end.

When I send the GIF in facebook chat via my browser, it animates fine. How can I send an animated GIF (or even better, HTML5 video) via the messenger API?

Here's a sample request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient":{
    "id":"<myid>"
  },
  "message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"image",
      "payload":{
        "url":"http://i.giphy.com/14aUO0Mf7dWDXW.gif"
      }
    }
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<mytoken>"
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code in my terminal only had the id and access token changed, and it worked! the gif was animating!

Comment: Thanks, it works in my bot as well, no changes required! If you want to add this as a solution I'll mark it solved.

Comment: haha it's fine, if it's okay just vote for the comment :D thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved on Facebook's end; the code I posted in the question now works fine (thanks [iownthegame](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3118585/iownthegame) for pointing this out).